# SwiftUI list line separatorStyle not work correctly with navigation

Tags: list, swiftui

I have try to hide and show separator line on 2 views
the first view I implement as below

```
struct FirstView: View {
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView{
         VStack{
            List{
               Text("test1")
               Text("test2")
            }
            .onAppear {UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none}
            .onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine }
            NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) {
                Text("next view")
            }
         }
      }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
   }
}
```

This will display none line on FirstView. 
when navigate to NextView which also have list the separate line is not show up.
After that navigate back to FirstView the separate line show up.

```
struct NextView: View {
   var body: some View {
      List{
          Text("test1")
          Text("test2")
      } 
   }
}
```

I am not sure is this bug or I coded wrong on somewhere.

Comment: did you try add in your NextView List  .onAppear {UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine }

Comment: I have try to add it and the line separator show up but when navigate back to firstView line separator still show up.

Comment: Here is used undocumented workaround (access to internal UITableView), with undocumented assumption (behaviour of onAppear/onDisappear), so why it should behave according expectation as it is formulated in question? Just thought...

Comment: If that the case what is the proper way to hide the separator line?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear` anywhere in your code before **the List appears** should work.

```
    init() {
    // To remove only extra separators below the list:
    UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()

    // To remove all separators including the actual ones:
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
}

var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when navigate back to firstview the separator line still show up.

Comment: @AchiraTrakansutleart than you should use clear color